# Generating Hexanacci numbers using fast exponentiation

Tags: c++, performance, numbers, formula, exponentiation

I've been trying to generate Hexanacci numbers using fast exponentiation, but I can't find the right formula! I assume it has to do with powers of 2, from which I substract numbers from this [sequence](http://oeis.org/A001792) (492 = 2 ^ 9 - 20; 976 = 2 ^ 10 - 48).

I generated a few numbers using [these](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-to-obtain-given-sum-by-repeated-throws-of-a-dice/), but the code is not time efficient enough (there's this programming site from my country, similar to Codeforces and the problem has a restricted time limit).

Comment: What are Hexanacci numbers?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: According to GeeksforGeeks, the hexanacci number is a generalization of the Fibonacci number where each term is the sum of the six preceding terms.

Comment: These are the numbers: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 63, 125, 248, 492, 976, 1936, 3840...

Comment: These also represent the number of ways to obtain sum N by rolling a dice multiple times - obtaining sum N can be done in the number-represented-by-the-N-th-number-of-the-sequence ways. ex: there are 125 ways to obtain sum 8 (1 + 1 + 6, 2 + 5 + 1, 1 + 6 + 1...).

Comment: My question is: how do I calculate the N-th hexanacci number, using fast exponentiation?

Comment: This will quickly overflow any standard integer type. Do you want an *exact* answer?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a closed-form formula you can compute it using matrix multiplication, or specifically matrix fast pow.

Specifically, let's assume the sequence is x(i).

Then we can construct a matrix A such that:

[x(i+1), x(i+2), x(i+3), x(i+4), x(i+5), x(i+6)]<sup>T</sup> = A * [x(i), x(i+1), x(i+2), x(i+3), x(i+4), x(i+5)]<sup>T</sup>

This matrix will look like:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now if you compute A<sup>n</sup> that allows you to make n steps at time:

[x(i+n), x(i+n+1), x(i+n+2), x(i+n+3), x(i+n+4), x(i+n+5)]<sup>T</sup> = A<sup>n</sup> * [x(i), x(i+1), x(i+2), x(i+3), x(i+4), x(i+5)]<sup>T</sup>

A<sup>n</sup> can be computed in O(log(n)) matrix multiplications.